# Como faço para informar se o usuário já existe quando apertar o botão salvar?

Tags: java, android

Como faço quando eu apertar o botão salvar e informar se o usuário já existe.

```
  public void salvar(){
   String comando = "";
   if (this.getId() == -1){
      comando = String.format("INSERT INTO cadastro (nomedousuario, senha) 
            VALUES ('%s','%s');");
    }
```

Comment: Faz um select consultando se o nome do usuario já existe.

Comment: Consegui fazer aqui, valeu.